# ng-class not adding the class when true

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to Angular and stucked.  Please see the following [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/D0SR43WII1dRyjUpBMmy?p=preview)

I have a ngcontroller that adds an array of menuItems to the scope.  I am using ngrepeat on the array of menuItems on a li element within ul.  Whenever the user clicks on an anchor within the li element, I am setting an "open" property to true on the selected menuItem.  i want to dynamically add the "open" class to the li element.

```
        <div data-ng-controller="MenuCtrl">
        <ul>
            <li data-ng-repeat="m in menuItems" data-ng-class="{open: {m.open}">
                <a data-ng-click="selectMenuItem(m)">
```

As you can see in the plunker, the class "open" is not added to the li element.  What am i doing wrong?

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://plnkr.co/edit/TirAAwQEY2NSVabIFdve?p=preview

Think you just had some syntax errors floating around in your ng-class definitions, it can just be a map from class name to property (truth property otherwise other syntax exists for comparing other values)

```
            <li data-ng-repeat="m in menuItems" data-ng-class="{open: m.open}">
```

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is wrong:

```
data-ng-class="{open: {m.open}"
```

Should be

```
data-ng-class="{open: m.open}"
```